# Expand environment variable from variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I have a code that looks like this:

```
my_var="MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR"
```

My question is, how do I get the value from the environment variable MY_ENV_VAR.

I have tried a lot of thing, but the main problem is that my_var is now a string.

The reason I would like to do this is because I have some environment variables that have almost the same name.

```
MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR=R1.2.3
MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR=R2.3.4

for vari in FIRST SECOND; do
    branch=MY_$( echo $vari )_ENV_VAR;
    echo $branch;
    echo ${branch};
    echo "${branch};
done;
```

I have tried a couple of other things as well. I my code I just have access to the FIRST and SECOND strings, I need to construct the name of the variable first.

I have looked for quite some time, and maybe I am just looking for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR=R1.2.3
MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR=R2.3.4

for vari in FIRST SECOND; do
    varName="MY_${vari}_ENV_VAR"
    branch=${!varName}
    echo "$branch"
done
```

Output:

```
R1.2.3
R2.3.4
```

`${!varName}` is known as [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and allows you to expand the variable called `varName`. Consult the bash [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for details.

---

If your shell does not support indirect expansion shown above, use `eval` instead:

```
MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR=R1.2.3
MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR=R2.3.4

for vari in FIRST SECOND; do
    branch=$(eval "echo \$MY_${vari}_ENV_VAR")
    echo "$branch"
done
```

Comment: _eval_, better known as _evil_ :/

Comment: 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: `eval` is not always evil. If you have no choice, then you have to use it. On the webpage you posted, there is a section on "Examples of good use of eval" which says "eval has other uses especially when creating variables out of the blue (indirect variable references)."

Comment: Just remember: `eval` should be treated as a last resort, not an alternative, method to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 1):

### Let's show you

```
MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR=R1.2.3
MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR=R2.3.4

for vari in FIRST SECOND; do
    branch="MY_${vari}_ENV_VAR"
    echo "branch variable: $branch"
    echo "branch variable indirection: ${!branch}"
done
```

### Output

```
branch variable: MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR
branch variable indirection: R1.2.3
branch variable: MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR
branch variable indirection: R2.3.4
```

### Doc

`${!branch}` is a [*variable indirection*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2BAC8-reference_variables)

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer. unfortunately that is a bashism and not POSIX.

Comment: I don't recommend you to use `eval`, but to rethink your problem, I'm pretty sure you don't need indirection there. But if you really need it, you should use bash (this trick or arrays) or perl